# Determine if app is active during working shift change

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, session, timespan

VB2012: My application requires a user to sign in. Once signed in the app is minimized to the notification area so at times the user forgets to sign out once their work shift is over. I am trying to detect when the working shift changes and if the app is still active then notify the current user that they should exit the application and re-sign in.

Here is what I have so far on a timer that determines when the last working shift started:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'assemble the shifts start date/times
    Dim currDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now                     'current date and time
    Dim currDate As DateTime = currDateTime.Date                    'current date only
    Dim mdPriDate As DateTime = currDate.AddDays(-1).AddHours(22)   'prior day midnight shift starts at 22:00
    Dim amCurDate As DateTime = currDate.AddHours(6)                'current day morning shift starts at 06:00
    Dim pmCurDate As DateTime = currDate.AddHours(14)               'current day evening shift starts at 14:00
    Dim mdCurDate As DateTime = currDate.AddHours(22)               'current day midnight shift starts at 22:00

    'create a dictionary comprised of the shift start times and TimeSpans from current time
    Dim dictShifts As New Dictionary(Of DateTime, TimeSpan) From
        {
            {mdPriDate, currDateTime.Subtract(mdPriDate)}, _
            {amCurDate, currDateTime.Subtract(amCurDate)}, _
            {pmCurDate, currDateTime.Subtract(pmCurDate)}, _
            {mdCurDate, currDateTime.Subtract(mdCurDate)}
        }

    'output variables
    Debug.Print("currDate    ={0}", currDate.ToString("s"))
    Debug.Print("currDateTime={0}", currDateTime.ToString("s"))
    Debug.Print("mdPriDate   ={0} hoursElapsed={1}", mdPriDate.ToString("s"), currDateTime.Subtract(mdPriDate).TotalHours)
    Debug.Print("amCurDate   ={0} hoursElapsed={1}", amCurDate.ToString("s"), currDateTime.Subtract(amCurDate).TotalHours)
    Debug.Print("pmCurDate   ={0} hoursElapsed={1}", pmCurDate.ToString("s"), currDateTime.Subtract(pmCurDate).TotalHours)
    Debug.Print("mdCurDate   ={0} hoursElapsed={1}", mdCurDate.ToString("s"), currDateTime.Subtract(mdCurDate).TotalHours)

    'get only the timespans that are in the past and then order ascending by timespan. the first item should be the most current
    'shift start time.
    Dim vpLastShift As KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, TimeSpan) = dictShifts.Where(Function(x, y) x.Value.TotalHours >= 0).OrderBy(Function(z) z.Value).First()
    Debug.Print("last shift date={0} hoursElapsed={1}", vpLastShift.Key.ToString("s"), vpLastShift.Value.TotalHours)
End Sub
```

I am essentially calculating when the last working shift start occurred. Here is a sample of the debug:

```
currDate    =2018-04-22T00:00:00
currDateTime=2018-04-22T00:40:15
mdPriDate   =2018-04-21T22:00:00 hoursElapsed=2.670896461
amCurDate   =2018-04-22T06:00:00 hoursElapsed=-5.329103539
pmCurDate   =2018-04-22T14:00:00 hoursElapsed=-13.329103539
mdCurDate   =2018-04-22T22:00:00 hoursElapsed=-21.329103539
last shift date=2018-04-21T22:00:00 hoursElapsed=2.670896461
```

Questions: Is this logic efficient and sound to calculate the last working shift start time? What about a notification to the user? I am thinking that if the app is active 15 minutes before the last shift change and also active 15 minutes after shift change then I should notify the user to sign out. Looking for suggesttions on how I can manage that.

Comment: Hallo, why not signing him off **automatically** at shift end?